# How to add the marketing materials to Google Workspace Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We successfully submitted an OAuth App and got verification approval -
But throw out the process, we didn't understand where we uploaded our branding assets to be displayed on the marketplace; we read the documentation, but we couldn't find it during the process.
Pls help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In `API & Services > OAuth Consent screen` you specify the branding information that is shown in the OAuth consent screen of the applications that use that cloud project. See https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/configure-oauth-consent-screen.

In the [Google Workspace Marketplace SDK](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com) you specify the listing assets. See https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk.